# Unable to get the Lookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

Following code:

```
For i = startRow To startRow + (nRows - 1)    
Set lookUp = Range(col & i)
Range("I" & i) = IIf(WorksheetFunction.lookUp(lookUp, Sheets("P&C curves").Columns("A")) = lookUp, 1, 0)
Range("J" & i) = IIf(WorksheetFunction.lookUp(lookUp, Sheets("G Curve").Columns("A")) = lookUp, 1, 0)      
Next i
```

In the code, the first time I call `WorksheetFunction.lookUp` everything works fine, namely it fills the column with 1 where it find something, else it puts a zero, but the second line does not work. I receive the error:

> Unable to get lookup property of the worksheetfunction class.

Why does this happen? If I try to use the same logic directly in the excel sheet it works?

Would really appreciate any help...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
For I = startRow To startRow + (nRows - 1)
    Set Lookup = Range(col & I)

    On Error Resume Next

    Ret = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Lookup, Sheets("P&C curves").Columns("A"))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Range("I" & I) = 0
        Err.Clear
    Else
        If Ret = Lookup Then Range("I" & I) = 1 Else Range("I" & I) = 0
    End If

    Ret = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Lookup, Sheets("G Curve").Columns("A"))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Range("J" & I) = 0
        Err.Clear
    Else
        If Ret = Lookup Then Range("J" & I) = 1 Else Range("J" & I) = 0
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support, yes this is the logic I need to have implemented, but copying how you wrote it slows everything down due to the IF Else statements.....In my code the first line is perfectly working and does what you describe in the first part, but strangely the second line does not work??

Comment: That is because it errors out since it doesn't find a value. How many rows are we talking about? I just tested the above code for 700 rows and it finished it in a blink of an eye... if I may say so.

Comment: Okay could explain a bit more on the it errors out, I mean if I remove the second line it runs completely through for the first line. Often it doesn't find a value, so it puts zero in the cell, why does this behaviour does not work anymore if the second line is there?

Comment: The first line works because you have the search value in "P&C curves" but it fails on the 2nd line because the search value is not in "G Curve". Lookup() return a #N/A in such a case and hence you get the error.

Comment: Alternatively you can use this principle to ignore the errors `=IF(ISERROR(LOOKUP(A2,'P&C curves'!A:A)),0,LOOKUP(A2,'P&C curves'!A:A))` and incorporate that in your VBA code

Comment: Okay I figured out the issue, the point is that in the first line it starts with a case where it finds the value, then it runs through, in the second line it starts with a non-matching case, then it stops instead of continuing, if i would start in the second line with a matching case it would work (i did the tests), this is really weird excel behaviour, so thanks for your help, will then implement the error handling

Answer (score 2):

In this case error is coming due to lookup value is not available in array.
IF we write formula in excel file and we don't have lookup value in array then it simply return `#N/A` but in VBA it return `Unable to get lookup property of the worksheetfunction class`. instead of `#N/A`. So, You need to add On error resume next on top of it.

Second way is instead formula you can use loop