# Excel VBA Vlookup Runtime Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a function that will run a loop that tests to see whether or not an organization (var 'org') has a campaign that has actually started yet, hence 'If (result <= Now()'. There is an unspecified number of campaigns which I'm finding in the spreadsheet with 'CountIf' and is given to the module as 'total'.

In the spreadsheet when the cell which needs to have a valid campaign finds that the campaign randomly guessed in another cell isn't valid, it goes to the VBA function, giving the function both the organization ID and the total number of campaigns under that organization.

My codes:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim x
    x = MacIDGen(111, 11)
End Sub

Function MacIDGen(org, total)

    Dim iteration As Boolean, result As Range

    For current = 1 To total
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(org & " " & current, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Donations").Range("C:E"), 3, False)
        If (result <= Now()) Then
            MacIDGen = org & " " & current & " Test successful"
            current = total
        End If
    Next current

End Function
```

Spreadsheet structure:

```
Org ID- Org Camp Count- Camp No.- Valid Camp No.
62      1               1         62 1
14      2               1         14 1
2       4               4         2 4
79      5               4         79 4
```

During debugging in VBA editor the `runtime error 1004` crops up and when executing in the spreadsheet the function seeming does nothing and the cell adopts last valid value before fairly quickly refreshing cells.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Try to change result's type from Range to Variant. VLookup() returns values (string,double) or Error type.

Comment: This has been covered many times before :)

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593959/using-vlookup-from-a-vba-module-in-excel-to-check-if-value-is-in-table) is one example... [ANOTHER ONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057369/vlookup-in-vba-within-a-for-loop)... And [ANOTHER ONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634611/unable-to-get-the-lookup-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class) on the same lines...

Comment: @SiddharthRout So in your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057369/vlookup-in-vba-within-a-for-loop. Whats the 'On Error Resume Next' actually doing? How does that fix the issue?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` suppresses the error message in case the `Vlookup` doesn't return anything. And then we can check whether there is something in `result` or not before proceeding to the line `If (result <= Now()) Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for those who may stumble across this later, here's my working code:

```
Function MacIDGen2(org As Integer, total As Integer)

Dim iteration As Boolean, trueArray() As String, totalTrue As String, randArrNo As Integer, result
ReDim trueArray(total)
totalTrue = 0

For current = 0 To total - 1
    On Error Resume Next
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(org & " " & current + 1, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Campains").Range("C:E"), 3, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If (Not IsNull(result)) Then
        If (result <= Now()) Then
            trueArray(totalTrue) = current + 1
            totalTrue = totalTrue + 1
        End If
    End If

Next current

If (totalTrue > 0) Then
    randArrNo = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, totalTrue - 1)
    MacIDGen2 = org & " " & trueArray(randArrNo)
Else
    MacIDGen2 = 0
End If

End Function
```

Basically the 'On Error Resume Next' fixed the issue. Then I added the If IsNull check for the result.

I've also slightly improved the code in that it now randomly selects any  one of the valid campaigns. Before it would simply pick the first valid campaign it finds.

Those with a keen eye may also notice that the sheet I'm referencing in the updated version is different to the one in my original code. The original sheet was wrong and I was referencing the same sheet I was calling the module from, ending in a circular reference. This tiny little discrepancy cost me over a couple of hours of hair tearing confusion.