# A worksheet function inside a worksheet function

Tags: vba, excel

When working inside worksheets we can nest functions for example:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C8, [Table4], 1,0),"")

but when I tried doing this in a macro it produces an error, This line of code is the one I was trying to apply:

```
  Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError ((Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C8"), [Table4],  1, 0), "")
```

So, How to nest worksheet functions in VBA?

Comment: I do not understand sir, do you mean we can not nest worksheet functions?

Comment: You do not nest Vlookup with iserror in VBA. See my comments [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971739/excel-vba-vlookup-runtime-error-1004)

Comment: ?! (there are not so many words in this sentence to understand it so wrongly). You added the VB.NET tag; I replaced it with the VBA tag and wrote a comment letting you know about it: this is a VBA question and thus should be VBA-tagged, not VB.NET (VBA and VB.NET are completely different things).

Comment: So when vlookup encounters a blank cell we should use if statement to recover this error?

Comment: @varocarbas Aha thank you >>>> mistakenly

Comment: @MohammadTaha: Not only a blank cell. A Vlookup might not find a match and hence we use `On Error Resume Next` If you read the complete comment then you will see that I have mentioned that there as well.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the exact error message/number you are getting?

Comment: @Blackhawk Sir the error message indicates that it is not able to use vlookup function..sorry I do not remember the number... if I Encounter the same error message I'll tell you

Comment: @SiddharthRout There is no problem with nesting functions in VBA. Only problem is the parenthesis don't match. OP has too many opening but not enough closing.

Comment: @D_Bester: Yes, that is a syntax error. However in this case even if you rectify the parenthesis, it, won't work :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue but this didn't give an error: Debug.Print (Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C8"), Sheet1.Range("a"), 1, 0), ""))

Comment: @SiddharthRout O I understand now: If the vlookup throws an error then IfError is not going to avoid the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the `.Worksheetfunction` method and use instead:

```
v = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(Range("C8"), [Table4], 1, 0), "")
```

or:

```
With Application
    v = .IfError(.VLookup(Range("C8"), [Table4], 1, 0), "")
End With
```

Using `Application` without `.Worksheetfunction` returns a variant which will allow for errors or arrays in arguments and return values. So you can also look up a vector of values eg use: `Range("C8:C10")` in place of `Range("C8")`.

Comment: Really??! thant's very beautiful mr @lori_m thank you

Comment: Yes, this appears to be not widely known or documented but can be very useful. (Please indicate if this answers the question - thanks.)

Comment: thank you for this code I have many troubles using Vlookup of VBA,, I am still learning